# Finding the ascii value for shift-in shift-out in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ascii

I've some records which are really messed up.
My team lead told me to find out the position of characters with ascii value 14 and 15.

I've a query

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(14),X_CUSTOMER_COMMENTS)
FROM vp_service_requests;

SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(15),X_CUSTOMER_COMMENTS)
FROM vp_service_requests;
```

which returns 0 because i wasn't able to find char with 14 and 15 ascii value after google
search i found 14 and 15 ascii value are for shift in and shift out
how this represents on keyboard so i can try for it with CHAR(14) function.

Comment: Are you sure you need to find chars 14 and 15?  Where did  those come from?

Comment: @JNK I don't know my TL said to find char position with those ascii value.

Comment: I would circle back to verify.  Tell him they are non-printable characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a holdover from the old DOS days, Windows still allows you to enter certain old ASCII keys from the keyboard by pressing and holding the ALT key, followed by the three-digit code you wish to enter (from the 10-key pad, not the numeric row atop the keyboard), eg for 14, type ALT-014.

However, some of the lower-level codes are inherited from old terminal functions, eg ASCII 7 is a bell, 8 is a backspace, eg, and rather that typing a *character*, they cause the cursor to behave a certain way or induce an application to respond in a defined manner. You can embed a CHAR(XX) value for testing simply by concatenating the value into a string and INSERTing it into your test table.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Ctrl-N and Ctrl-O although I doubt this will help.

Try loading the records into a good editor and look at them in HEX. Weird characters should stick out like a sore thumb